# Do React unique key warnings appear in production (in Next, specifically)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm getting a React duplicate key warning in development. Grepping for all of my `map`s and manually reviewing them hasn't led me anywhere. So, I started reversing commits to find the offender, but ended up *way* back without finding it, and I was pretty sure this wasn't happening a few days ago. So, I went and looked at what was in production, and I'm not seeing the errors there. So I checked out the production build, and *am* seeing the errors. So I'm wondering, does either React normally by itself, or something in the way NextJS builds static pages, suppress the warning in production?

NB: the actual warning is being generated for a 3rd-party component, the [React DatoCMS](https://github.com/datocms/react-datocms) `<StructredText>` component. If Next/React *isn't* suppressing the warning, then my suspicion will be something broke in an update to the DatoCMS API, and I'll reach out to them. If it is or may be suppressing the warning, then ... I'll keep digging.

Comment: If you fetch data with `useEffect`, this might be related to the strictmode of React. Try [removing](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode) `<Strictmode>` and see if it's okay in development. This happens only in development though. Production shouldn't show any warnings.

Comment: I fully expected this to work, and was going to ask if it wasn't just hiding things. But ... it doesn't work. :) The problem is still there without strict mode.

Comment: Then, as you stated, my next suspect would be any 3rd party plugin. You could create a page with zero dependencies to test that easily.